# Using ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator on impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'm trying to use the ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator  on an impex. I have some examples with  the class ClassificationAttributeTranslator working but can't make this work.

```
$productCatalog = myCatalog
$classificationCatalog = myClassification

$catalogVersion = catalogversion(catalog(id[default = $productCatalog]), version[default = 'Staged'])[unique = true, default = $productCatalog:Staged]
$clAttrModifiers = system = '$classificationCatalog', version = '1.0', translator = de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator, lang = es
//Q_1001 is the ClassAttributeAssignment ID
$feature1 = @Q_1001 [$clAttrModifiers];
//123012 is the product code and
INSERT_UPDATE  Product; code[unique = true]; $feature1; $catalogVersion
; 123012 ; TEST VALUE;
```

I'm getting this error

```
INSERT_UPDATE  Product;code[unique = true];@Q_1001 [system = 'myClassification', version = '1.0', translator = de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator, lang = es];catalogversion(catalog(id[default = myCatalog]), version[default = 'Staged'])[unique = true, default = myCatalog:Staged];# invalid special value translator class 'de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator' - cannot create due to java.lang.InstantiationException: de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator
,,,,invalid special value translator class 'de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator' - cannot create due to java.lang.InstantiationException: de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator;123012;TEST VALUE;
```

Comment: Whats the error? I only see 'Blockquote'

Comment: Really?  Any way I did wat I wanted using this guide 
https://hybrisworld.wordpress.com/pcm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeTranslator` and not `de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeValueTranslator`